# Workflow Tasks list giving error "Sorry, something went wrong"

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, tasks, workflow-tasks-list

[image]

There is a "Workflow Tasks" list in my SharePoint online site and it is giving error as "Sorry, something went wrong" whenever I click on that list.

I am unable to see the workflow tasks that were executed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can add **?contents=1** to the current page URL to view a 'Web Parts Maintenance Page'. From there you will be able to see the web parts on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Sanap said you can use the Web Parts Maintenance Page to do some troubleshooting with more detailed information about the error. You can learn more information here:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/open-and-use-the-web-part-maintenance-page-eff9ce22-d04a-44dd-ae83-ac29a5e396c2

And for the workflow you can have a check on the hidden workflow history list. The url will be like

http://yoursite/Lists/Workflow%20History/AllItems.aspx